# New iTunes mandatory about Xcode version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, xcode5.0.1

New iTunes is asking to build application using Xcode 5.1.1 or later. Is there any work around to upload application built on Xcode5.0

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

No, you must build with the latest version of Xcode (preferably Xcode 6.1) so that users of newer devices / OSes get the best possible experience.

Updating from 5.0 to 5.1 shouldn't be that much of a stretch as the SDK didn't change a lot between iOS 7 and iOS 7.1.